# circular progressbar around timer that changes color as time progresses

Tags: javascript, html, css

[This is a link to my code](https://codepen.io/ShaShah/pen/gGXKaW)

I was wondering if there is a way for my to build a circular progressbar along the circumference of the timer which would change color as time progresses?

**P. S. I only want to use HTML, CSS and JavaScript**

```
 <div id="quiz"><br>
      <div class="progress">
       <div class="progress-value">
        <span id="time">05:00 </span>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[FYR: this is something on the lines of what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhtFL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this using an HTML Canvas and drawing an arc:

```
<canvas id="progress-bar"></canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('progress-bar');
    if(canvas){
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
            centerX = canvas.width / 2,
            centerY = canvas.height / 2,
            radius = 50;

        // completedPercentage would be dynamically set 
        // from 0 to 1 based on what % of time had elapsed.
        // I've hardcoded it to 40% here to demo the circle.
        var completedPercentage = 0.40;

        var startAngle = 1.5 * Math.PI,
            endAngle = -.5 * Math.PI + (completedPercentage * Math.PI * 2);

        context.lineWidth = 10;

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle);
        context.strokeStyle = '#060';
        context.stroke();

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, endAngle, -.5 * Math.PI);
        context.strokeStyle = '#0F0';
        context.stroke();
    }

</script>
```

You can position that Canvas behind your #time element and then however you're updating that value also trigger a call to this JavaScript updating the 'completedPercentage' value. I've set most of the values as nicely named variables so that you should be able to see what to swap in, swap out, and adjust to get the circle the size/shape/color that you want.

The little bit of math involving PI is just to get the arc to start from the top. Typically Math.PI will have your circle start from the right side (0), so this adjusts it 3/4 of a rotation so that it starts from the "12 o'clock" position that we tend to think of with regards to circles and time.